Call a function in SQL Server and Oracle with same syntax
To call a function, SQL Server uses the following syntax:
SELECT dbo.GetSquare(Item) AS SquareValue 
FROM Squares;

In Oracle the same can be achieved with:
SELECT GetSquare(Item) AS SquareValue 
FROM Squares;

The syntax is almost the same, except SQL Server requires the schema (dbo.) before the function name.
Is it possible to write an identical statement to call a function for both DBMS in 2024?

Your SQL Server syntax will also work in Oracle.

Have you tried SELECT owner_name.GetSquare(Item) as SquareValue FROM Squares; in Oracle? it should work. If the owner of the GetSquare function is called dbo then you should be able to use exactly the same query.

kfinity, it won't. MT0, adding owner_name will run the query, but issue is that it requires DB schema to be named the same in SqlServer which is not acceptable.

Switching to inline table-valued function, but it's used differently than a scalar one.

You appear to have missed my point. The point was not to change the SQL Server user but to make sure the name of the Oracle user was DBO so that it matched the SQL Server user (that you cannot change).

MT0, thank you for thoughts. It's just either way a limiting factor, as there can be only one user with same name on Oracle per DB.

@Vy8 - I'm not sure why that's fundamentally different to only having one DBO schema in SQL Server. If you want to connect as different users and call that function then can't you create it under a new DBO user (schema) and grant execute privileges on that to your real users (possibly via a role)? That seems roughly the same...

Alex Poole, almost answered that by showing additional efforts needed to manage it.

What about creating a synonym in SQL Server for GetSquare which references the true owner dbo.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/synonyms/synonyms-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver16.  the synonym in the schema used would be getSquare(Item) which would then would then use dbo.getsquare(Item)  The synonym is just a pointer to the full path of the function and can be referenced in the source schema w/o specifiging the full object path due to the synonym handling it.

In Oracle, if you use:
SELECT owner
FROM   all_objects
WHERE  object_type = 'FUNCTION'
AND    object_name = 'GETSQUARE';

It will tell you the owner of the function (which is probably your current user).
You can call the function using:
SELECT owner.GetSquare(Item) AS SquareValue 
FROM   Squares;

(Substituting owner with the actual name of the owner.)
If the Oracle  owner is named DBO (note: upper-case) then you will be able to use:
SELECT dbo.GetSquare(Item) AS SquareValue 
FROM   Squares;

and use the same query in SQL Server and Oracle.
(Note: your current Oracle user does not have to be called DBO, you just have to make the owner of the function be a user with the name DBO and then GRANT EXECUTE ON dbo.GetSquare TO your_current_user and then you can use it from your current user.)
fiddle

Alternatively, create an Oracle package named dbo that contains the function GetSquare:
CREATE PACKAGE dbo IS
  FUNCTION GetSquare(i_item IN Squares.Item%TYPE) RETURN Squares.Item%TYPE;
END;
/

CREATE PACKAGE BODY dbo IS
  FUNCTION GetSquare(i_item IN Squares.Item%TYPE) RETURN Squares.Item%TYPE
  IS
  BEGIN
    RETURN i_item * i_item;
  END GetSquare;
END dbo;
/

Then you can call:
SELECT dbo.GetSquare(Item) AS SquareValue 
FROM   Squares;

or:
SELECT owner_name.dbo.GetSquare(Item) AS SquareValue 
FROM   Squares;

fiddle

Thanks for sharing ideas. Either in SqlServer I should have a schema named *owner, so it brings additional management and is not acceptable. or in Oracle I must have a user named DBO which is also limiting factor having one user on same DB.

@Vy8 Added an alternative, create a PACKAGE in Oracle named DBO that contains the function.

MT0, that worked as a charm. You made my day. TYVM!
